# How to create empty row after every continuous 3 rows?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How to create empty row after every continuous 3 rows in LibreOffice Calc as like below?

**Original Rows:**

[image: aaaaaa.bbbbb.cccccc.ddddddd.]

**Expected Rows:**

[image]

If it is possible as per my expectation using LibreOffice Calc means guide me to get the above output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short of something like BASIC the best than can be achieved with ordinary formulae is to space out a copy of your data, rather than insert rows. So assuming `1` is in A2, in Row2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(MOD((ROW()-1),4)=0,"",OFFSET(A$2,ROW()-2-INT((ROW()-2)/4),))
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response.. But your steps for the output is not easy as for beginners. 1 in A2 means (A column, 2 row) is ok.. Where I create helper column and where I put the formulae, etc. if you don't mind, if possible can you guide me with easy steps?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is a process that does require a helper column, but not much of a formula. Still assuming `1` is in A2, populate a column with something like:

```
=INT((ROW()-2)/3)
```

copied down to suit. Then Edit > Copy > Edit > Paste Special...  and under `Selection` check `Numbers` only, <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Yes</kbd>.

Now select from ColumnA to your helper column and: Data > Subtotals... and for `1st Group` only, `Group by:` whatever is your helper column and `Calculate subtotals for:` that helper column only. The default Sum `Use function:` is fine then <kbd>OK</kbd> and delete the helper column.

More difficult to explain than to do, the advantage is that because the groupings can be achieved with such a simple formula whose results are converted to values anyway the process is versatile.